# Summation of a multinomial coefficient

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I was looking for a combinatorical explenation for this identity
$$\sum_{x_1+x_2+x_3 \le18}\binom{18}{x_1,x_2,x_3} = 4^{18}$$
A simple explenation would be enough,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This just the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) for $(1+a+b+c)^{18}$ where $a = b = c = 1$.

Just leave a comment, if you need a less simple explanation :-)

**Edit:** Please note, that at Wikipedia's page there's a bit different definition of multinomial than yours, i.e. $\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3}$ as compared to $\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4}$ where $k_4 = n-k_1-k_2-k_3$.